# Simplifying a function of $\ln(x)$

Tags: functions

I was asked to convert the function

$$\frac{1}{x \ln x \sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}$$

into a function in the expression

$$\frac{1}{x \sqrt{f(x)}}$$

for the domain $x > e$

but I can't seem to find how I can convert it into the answer:

$$\frac{1}{x \ln x \sqrt{(\ln x)^4 - (\ln x)^2}}$$

My instinct was to use the difference of two squares:

$$\frac{1}{x \ln x \sqrt{(\ln x+1)(\ln x-1)}}$$

but I'm still stuck because that method doesn't work.

Can someone help?

Comment: Just make $ \ln x \sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}=\sqrt{f(x)}$ which give  $ (\ln x)^2(\ln x)^2-1)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a simple calcul

If $x > e$ then

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x \ln x \sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}&=\frac{1}{x \ln x \sqrt{ (\frac{ln x}{ln x})^2(\ln x)^2-1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{x  \dfrac{\ln x}{ln x} \sqrt{ (ln x)^2(\ln x)^2-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{x \sqrt{ (ln x)^4-(\ln x)^2}} 
\end{align}

Comment: Damn... thanks so much!

Comment: @BobSmith you are welcome :)

Comment: This is wrong. For $0<x<1/e$ the function takes on negative values, but your final expression just takes on positive values.

Comment: @The_lost,  please correct your answer,  to include also the case where x is smaller than 1/e.

Comment: Please see the answer below of egreg.

Comment: @dmtri thank you, it is ok now ?

Comment: Nice of you!) :

Comment: @dmtri thank you :)

Comment: @The_lost   Now it’s even wronger than before

Comment: @egreg could you explain please?

Comment: I should have mentioned $ x > e $

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=({\log x})^{2}(({\log x})^{2}-1)$ will work.

Answer (score 3):

The function is defined for
\begin{cases}
x>0 \\[4px]
\ln x\ne0 \\[4px]
(\ln x)^2-1>0
\end{cases}
The third condition (together with the first) becomes $\ln x<-1$ or $\ln x>1$, that is, $0<x<1/e$ or $x>e$.

The second condition is $x\ne1$, which is implied by the third condition.

Your function can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{x\ln x\sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}=
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{(\ln x)^4-(\ln x)^2}} & 0<x<1/e \\[6px]
\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{(\ln x)^4-(\ln x)^2}} & x>e
\end{cases}
$$
It would be a mistake to just bring $\ln x$ as $(\ln x)^2$ inside the square root for the case $0<x<1/e$, because in this case the value of the function is negative.

The mistake would be the same as writing $1/\sqrt{x^2}=1/x$, which only holds for $x>0$.